# Different Navigation Types Between Pages

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make an app with a Main Page that is a plain Content Page (i.e. no toolbar) which has a button that leads into a Navigation Page (with toolbar). I'm struggling to find any resources to help me out in this specific case.

I have tried the following. In my `App.xaml`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new App5.MainPage();
        Pallets = new NavigationPage(new Pallets()); //Error: 'Pallets' is a type but is used like a variable
    }
    ...
}
```

Above is the error I get on `Pallets`. I could change Pallets for `MainPage` and write the whole app with Navigation pages, which I will do for now, but I would prefer not to.

In my `MainPage.xaml.cs`, I'm trying to switch the view when the button is clicked:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ...
    async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Pallets());
    }
}
```

I have seen examples such as [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/Hierarchical) that include Navigation Page to Navigation Page buttons, but not plain Content Page to Navigation Page buttons.

Comment: Pallets pallets = new NavigationPage(...

Comment: if you want to go from A to B without using NavigationPage, you probably need to do it by just reassigning the App.MainPage to B

Comment: I got an Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage' to 'App5.Pallets' for the first suggestion. Sorry if I missed something, I am a novice at app development.

I'll try the second as well. Do I make a method in App to reassign the MainPage?

Thanks so much!

Comment: sorry, I assumed that Pallets was the correct type.  just use var page = new NavigationPage(...

Comment: I seem to have found the solution! I gave up too soon.
public void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Pallets());
        } is what I needed, App contains only the MainPage setter. Solution derived from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701621/how-to-navigate-one-content-page-to-another-content-page-from-client-project-io. Sorry for taking your time, but thanks so much for the help.