# Navigation in Xamarin.Forms not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation

The navigation doesn't work by setting the Mainpage as the navigation page or by setting the Mainpage to be another content page  as i tried the solution Here:  [How to navigate one Content page to another Content page from client project (IOS/Android) in xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701621/how-to-navigate-one-content-page-to-another-content-page-from-client-project-io)

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App14
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Current.MainPage = new Page1();


    }


}
}
```

If I run the above code i don't see any Content The app just load and terminates

```
    using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using Xamarin.Forms;

   namespace App14
   {
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
  {
    public MainPage()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage();
        Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1())




    }


}
 }
```

and if tried making the MainPage a navigation Page and Pushasync code it won't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `App.xaml.cs`, which inherits from `Application` should be loading your `MainPage` and for navigation, it should be wrapped in a `NavigationPage`.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        MainPage = navigationPage;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks i helped me but how to write code with in the mainpage.xaml.cs or Page1.xaml.cs files that pushasync the pages

Comment: If you're trying to push a new page from inside that page and the current page is already inside a NavigationPage all you have to do is Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(), true);

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to lauch your app having its root page to be `Page1`.

If this is true then you are writing navigation logic at a wrong place. You should remove navigation logic from your `MainPage's` constructor and write your first page navigation into `App.cs` class as follows:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1 ());
    }
}
```

***Otherwise***,

If you want to launch your app with having `MainPage` as your root page and then immediately want to push `Page1` onto navigation stack then:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        var navPage = new NavigationPage(new App14.MainPage()); 
        Application.Current.MainPage = navPage; 

        navPage.PushAsync(new Page1());
    }
}
```

For more detail on navigation in Xamarin.Forms [click here](https://xamarinhelp.com/navigating-xamarin-forms/).